# Position sticky image is not working, when I scroll

Tags: css, position, sticky

I have a problem with sticky image. I give `top: 0`  but it does not work, also I try `display: initial` but nothing happens. I need when scroll section, image must be sticky on the top until end of section. Before I think the reason is due to parent element due to `position: relative`, but can not fix

```css
.player-about {
        padding-top: 26px;
        padding-bottom: 96px;
        height: 1000px
}
.player-about-content {
        padding-top: 34px;
        border-top: 1px solid #98a2b3;
        position: relative;
        display: flex;
}

.player-about-content-text {
        width: 55%;
}
p {
        text-align: justify;
}
.player-about-content-img {
        position: sticky;
        top: 0;
        width: 45%;
        display: flex;
        justify-content: flex-end;
              
}
```

```html
<section class="player-about">
            <div class="player-about-container container">
                <div class="player-about-content">
                    <div class="player-about-content-text">
                        <h4>Haqqında</h4>
                        <p>
                        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer sagittis diam molestie diam aliquet fringilla. Aenean scelerisque nulla vestibulum ipsum lobortis, posuere scelerisque dolor posuere. Sed auctor nulla ut erat lobortis finibus. Aliquam nec risus a lectus aliquet venenatis a vel erat. Ut consectetur ut quam quis accumsan. Quisque ut viverra nisl. Phasellus sollicitudin odio vitae enim cursus, a feugiat nisl aliquam. Pellentesque mi nisl, imperdiet sit amet nisl in, lacinia mattis eros. Maecenas quis tempor lacus.

Donec tempor nisi at condimentum accumsan. Praesent eu dolor placerat, tincidunt magna quis, congue nibh. Donec nec ipsum facilisis, porta velit id, scelerisque est. Phasellus pretium at nisl non luctus. Maecenas pellentesque elementum ante. Quisque vitae luctus ex, at tincidunt nisi. Vivamus accumsan, lectus suscipit congue iaculis, lectus velit varius eros, et dignissim nunc lorem vel sapien. Praesent quam odio, dignissim vel vulputate nec, auctor sit amet erat. Morbi dapibus ante at fermentum aliquam. Phasellus ac accumsan velit, in interdum dui. Suspendisse potenti. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Fusce lobortis, dui in cursus laoreet, odio enim sagittis lectus, sed faucibus tortor purus auctor lacus.

Nulla porta justo at elit mollis, tempor imperdiet odio dictum. Phasellus efficitur eleifend dolor vel aliquet. Nam pretium tortor ac dui scelerisque rutrum quis sed tellus. Cras luctus in quam ac cursus. Duis tincidunt neque magna, a cursus urna dignissim nec. Maecenas accumsan leo sed neque egestas sollicitudin. Vivamus sapien enim, elementum nec urna venenatis, ultrices tempus sapien. Nullam nec laoreet mauris. Sed vestibulum viverra nibh, luctus consequat eros tincidunt non. Pellentesque at mauris tempor, sagittis leo non, fringilla ante. Maecenas in imperdiet felis, in rhoncus lorem. Aliquam non enim odio.
                         </p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="player-about-content-img">
                        <img src="https://images.freeimages.com/images/previews/531/letter-c-1641882.png" alt="logo">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
```

Comment: you are using `player-about-content-img` but declared `player-content-img`

Comment: @Ofsen actually I use SASS but can not run it here. That's why I converted normal CSS and I made a class name mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the `player-about-content` has display flex, the two child divs `player-about-content-text` and `player-about-content-img` will take the full height.

To make the `position: sticky` work on the image you need to add it to the `img` tag itself.

So something like this should work:

```css
.player-about {
    padding-top: 26px;
    padding-bottom: 96px;
    height: 1000px
}
.player-about-content {
    padding-top: 34px;
    border-top: 1px solid #98a2b3;
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
}

.player-about-content-text {
    width: 55%;
}
p {
    text-align: justify;
}
.player-about-content-img img { /* added the 'img' */
    position: sticky;
    top: 0;
    width: 45%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: flex-end;
          
}
```

```html
<section class="player-about">
            <div class="player-about-container container">
                <div class="player-about-content">
                    <div class="player-about-content-text">
                        <h4>Haqqında</h4>
                        <p>
                        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer sagittis diam molestie diam aliquet fringilla. Aenean scelerisque nulla vestibulum ipsum lobortis, posuere scelerisque dolor posuere. Sed auctor nulla ut erat lobortis finibus. Aliquam nec risus a lectus aliquet venenatis a vel erat. Ut consectetur ut quam quis accumsan. Quisque ut viverra nisl. Phasellus sollicitudin odio vitae enim cursus, a feugiat nisl aliquam. Pellentesque mi nisl, imperdiet sit amet nisl in, lacinia mattis eros. Maecenas quis tempor lacus.

Donec tempor nisi at condimentum accumsan. Praesent eu dolor placerat, tincidunt magna quis, congue nibh. Donec nec ipsum facilisis, porta velit id, scelerisque est. Phasellus pretium at nisl non luctus. Maecenas pellentesque elementum ante. Quisque vitae luctus ex, at tincidunt nisi. Vivamus accumsan, lectus suscipit congue iaculis, lectus velit varius eros, et dignissim nunc lorem vel sapien. Praesent quam odio, dignissim vel vulputate nec, auctor sit amet erat. Morbi dapibus ante at fermentum aliquam. Phasellus ac accumsan velit, in interdum dui. Suspendisse potenti. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Fusce lobortis, dui in cursus laoreet, odio enim sagittis lectus, sed faucibus tortor purus auctor lacus.

Nulla porta justo at elit mollis, tempor imperdiet odio dictum. Phasellus efficitur eleifend dolor vel aliquet. Nam pretium tortor ac dui scelerisque rutrum quis sed tellus. Cras luctus in quam ac cursus. Duis tincidunt neque magna, a cursus urna dignissim nec. Maecenas accumsan leo sed neque egestas sollicitudin. Vivamus sapien enim, elementum nec urna venenatis, ultrices tempus sapien. Nullam nec laoreet mauris. Sed vestibulum viverra nibh, luctus consequat eros tincidunt non. Pellentesque at mauris tempor, sagittis leo non, fringilla ante. Maecenas in imperdiet felis, in rhoncus lorem. Aliquam non enim odio.
                         </p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="player-about-content-img">
                        <img src="https://images.freeimages.com/images/previews/531/letter-c-1641882.png" alt="logo">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
```